# In an angular4 application how do you alter data in a component which has a router-outlet from within the outlet?

Tags: angular, angular-router

I have run into this situation many times in developing angular2-4 applications. I still do not know the best way to solve this situation. The situation is this:

A component such as app.component.ts has a header. This header needs to react to user input which is occurring within components being generated in a router-outlet. In my experience it does not work to use event emitters to send the data outside of the router-outlet. What I have been doing is marking AppComponent as @Injectable(). I can then access methods and data by injecting app.component into whatever component that needs access to it. This does not seem like the proper way to do this. Is there a better solution for this problem?

This is an example of what I am talking about
app.component.html

```
<nav>My pretty navbar<md-icon *ngIf="userIsLoggedIn" svgIcon="hamburgerMenu"></md-icon></nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

app.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.sass'],
  providers: [ApplistenerService, LoginResourcesService]
})


    @Injectable()
    export class AppComponent{

        userIsLoggedIn=false;

        setUserIsLoggedInToTrue(){
            this.userIsLoggedIn=true;
        }

     }
```

loginService

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class LoginService {

    constructor(private app:AppComponent){}

    setLoginToTrue(){
        this.app.setUserIsLoggedInToTrue();
    }

}
```

In this example I inject the loginService into a component which is being routed to, and then within that inject appComponent in order to show that the user is logged in so that I can show the menu icon which should only be visible to users who are logged in.

This just feels wrong. Is there a better way to do this? Thanks for any help!

Comment: A shared service.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer but I would need that service to call a method within app.component, or apply a listener of some sort which listens to data in that service. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Use an observable in the service, subscribe to it from the component that wants to get notified, add notifications from anywhere (similar to what is shown in https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service)

Comment: You da man! Thanks, that works and feels better, than my previous solution. Although I have to be honest I was a bit skeptical that this would work, because in the docs it says in the first paragraph. "The scope of the service instance is the parent component and its children. Components outside this component subtree have no access to the service or their communications"... Is it correct to say that app.component is the parent of the components being generated in the router-outlet?

Comment: It means parent **and ancestors** or children **and descendants**. It's not only about direct parent/children. If you provide a service on a component all its descendants can inject it.